# How to parse a scraped JSON string

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, xpath, mechanize

I need to grab the values of a JSON string stored within a function in a script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    my.function("bar", {"foo1": false, "foo2": true, "foo3": "foobar!"});
</script>
```

I can get to the particular tag using Mechanize like so:

```
parser.xpath("//script[ contains(text(), 'my.function')]").text
```

but I'm not sure how to go on from there. How can I extract the JSON part of the string and convert it into a hash so that I can extract the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form doesn't change, you can do

```
JSON.parse(/\{.*\}/.match(txt)[0])
```

with `json` gem. Be aware that there are several points of failure - either check each step, or place a nice `rescue` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is a pure XPath 1.0 solution**:

**Use**:

```
concat('{',
       substring-before(
               substring-after(
                   substring-after(., 'my.function('),
                  '{'
                               ),
               ');'
                        )
       )
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "concat('{',
           substring-before(
                   substring-after(
                       substring-after(., 'my.function('),
                      '{'
                                   ),
                   ');'
                            )
           )
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 my.function("bar", {"foo1": false, "foo2": true, "foo3": "foobar!"});
</script>
```

**the XPath expression (above) is evaluated and the result is output**:

```
{"foo1": false, "foo2": true, "foo3": "foobar!"}
```